# Survfit function with regression

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I'm having trouble understanding what estimator the `survfit` function produces.

For example, if I call `survfit(Surv(start,Stop,Event) ~ sex)`, does this divide the data into male/female and produce a Kaplan Meier for each subset of data or otherwise. If otherwise which estimator does it produce? I can't seem to find the documentation.

Comment: should be, KM for each group. You can easily check by dividing data into two groups yourself and apply KM to each, compare to the curves produced by the call above

Comment: @adibender I have confirmed that it does divide and fit a KM estimator to each subset.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the  question, I can confirm that the using `survfit(Surv(start, event) ~ x)` subsets the data and fits a KM to each subset.

```r
x <- c(1:20)
y <- c(1:20)
xcen <- rep(1, 20)
ycen <- c(rep(1, 15), rep(0, 5))
df<-data.frame(
  start = cbind(x,y),
  status = cbind(xcen,ycen),
  sex = as.factor(c(rep(1,20),rep(0,20))))
survfit(Surv(start, status) ~ sex,data = df)
```

This is the same as fitting the KM for each subset.

Comment: would be good to actually show the two approaches, at least show code for both approaches. Also, for future questioning and answering you might consider https://reprex.tidyverse.org/